# Colocar divs en HTML

Tags: html, css, div

Estoy intentando hacer una galería con las carpetas que tengo en un directorio, y para ello uso php para recorrerlas. El caso es que se me da muy mal, fatal, el diseño, y lo que quiero hacer es que cada carpeta tenga de ancho 200px y de alto 200px, y a medida que se vayan acumulando en una fila, que el siguiente div pase para abajo. No se si me explico muy bien. Os dejo el código:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex: wrap">
            <?php foreach($listaCarpetas as $proyectos):?>
                <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
                    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
                        <?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>
                    </div>
                </a>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
```

Lo he intentado con `display: flex; flex: wrap` pero nada...
Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano!!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que presenta tu código?

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar! El problema es que quiero que los divs se ajusten a la pantalla con un tamaño de 200x200. Por ejemplo, tengo 10 divs, como no caben en una fila, que bajen a la siguiente os restantes. No sé si me explico bien...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como lo estás generando se ve todo en una fila porque tienes `display: flex` en el contenedor:

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex: wrap">
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Si quitas el `display: flex` y le añades un `display: inline-block` a los `div`, entonces obtendrás el efecto que esperas (que los `div` salten a la siguiente linea cuando ya no entre ninguno más:

```html
<div>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Como recomendación aparte, si vas a tener un número considerable de carpetas (o incluso si no), sería mejor tener los estilos en una hoja de estilos CSS y simplemente aplicarle una clase a los elementos.

Comment: Eso es lo que buscaba, el `inline-block` que hacía mucho que no diseñaba. 
Si si, todo con hojas de estilo, hago esto nada más para probar. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría utilizar bootsrap, tiene incorporado un sistema de Grids.

Entonces haces un div contenedor, una fila "row" y luego pones las columnas.
Lo bonito de esto es que se adapta a responsive.

Primero debes importar en el head, bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Luego ya el codigo de las columnas

```
<main class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($listaCarpetas as $proyectos):?>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="mostrarProyecto.php?ruta=<?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>">
                    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 10%;text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-size: 40px;border: 2px solid black;">
                        <?php echo $proyectos['file'];?>
                    </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>

    </div>
</main>
```

Puedes aprender bien bootstrap desde su página oficial 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Con Bootstrap no me funciona, ya lo probé, y me sale 1 div en cada fila...

Comment: Si te sale un div en cada fila es porque pusiste el "row" en donde no va. Probaste el código que te mandé?

Comment: Sí, exactamente el mismo, y no sale

Comment: Gracias por verlo, el div debe estar dentro del ciclo for. Mira el cambio que hice

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/josbert/pen/aaoOEx

Puedes ver este ejemplo, quizás te pueda ayudar mucho